# ng-click(s) does not work in partial view

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to render partial view on click, which has controller in it.

Layout/Index page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="AngularDemo">
    <head>
        ..
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside>
            <ul class="nav nav-list" ng-controller="Navigations as nav">
                <li class=""><a href="#" data-thisdiv="HomeDiv" ng-click="nav.showHomeDiv($event)">Home</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#" data-thisdiv="FedbackDiv" ng-click="nav.showFeedbackDiv($event)"> Feedbacks</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <section id="MainBody"></section>
    </body>
</html>
```

controller.js

```
myApp.controller("Navigations", ["$compile", function ($compile) {
    var $this = this;
    this.showFeedbackDiv = function ($event) {
        var compiledeHTML = $compile("<div load-Div></div>")($this);
        $("#MainBody").append(compiledeHTML);
        $(".Division").hide();
        $("." + $(event.currentTarget).data("thisdiv")).show();

    };
}]).directive('loadDiv', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/Default/GetFeedbackView',
        controller: 'Feedback'
    };
});

myApp.controller("Feedback", ['AngService', '$element', function(AngService, $element) {
    this.feedbackData = {};
    var $this = this;
    this.ShowFeedbacks = function () {
        AngService.ShowFeedbacks().then(function (response) {
            $this.allFeedbacks = JSON.parse(response.data);
            console.log($this.allFeedbacks);
            $("#ShowFeedbacksModal").modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true });
        }, function (response) {
            alert('Error in getting feedbacks');
        });
    };
}]);
```

partial View :

```
<div class="Division FedbackDiv" style="margin-top:40px" ng-controller="Feedback as fb">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            Feedback form
            <span style="cursor:pointer;" class="pull-right" ng-click="fb.ShowFeedbacks()"><i class="fa fa-adn"></i></span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

When i click on "show Feedbacks" nothing happens
error :

> TypeError: a.$new is not a function
>           at g (angular.js:6970)
>           at M (angular.js:7618)
>           at angular.js:7854
>           at angular.js:12914
>           at h.$eval (angular.js:14123)
>           at h.$digest (angular.js:13939)
>           at h.$apply (angular.js:14227)
>           at p (angular.js:9493)
>           at J (angular.js:9678)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular.js:9621)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should pass $scope in $compile; $scope should be injected into the controller; if you inspect the object this, it's not scope

instead of

```
    var compiledeHTML = $compile("<div load-Div></div>")($this);
```

try

```
    var compiledeHTML = $compile("<div load-Div></div>")($scope);
```

To inject $scope

```
    myApp.controller('Navigations', ['$compile', '$scope', function ($compile, $scope) { ... }])
```

Comment: as i mentioned before, you will have to inject $scope to controller

*let me edit my orig post

Answer (score 1):

remove ng-controller="Feedback as fb from partial and add controllerAs : fb to loadDiv config

```
.directive('loadDiv', function () {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/Default/GetFeedbackView',
    controller: 'Feedback',
    controllerAs : 'fb'
  };
```

Comment: I removed ng-controller="Feedback as fb" from partial view and added controllerAs : fb to loadDiv

.directive('loadDiv', function () {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/Default/GetFeedbackView',
    controller: 'Feedback',
    controllerAs : 'fb'
  };

eror : ReferenceError: fb is not defined

Comment: Do call Feedback controller?

Comment: may be help u http://blog.richpollock.com/2014/10/angular-js-tabs-directive-with-dynamic-loading-of-partial-templates-and-controllers/